# NodeJS: How to stop code execution till create operation to MySQL completes

Tags: mysql, node.js, synchronous

I have a very basic scenario, I am making a create operation call to MySQL in my NodeJS application. Once I get result of create operation (success or failure) I have to execute some code.

But now due to asynchronous behavior of NodeJS my code which is dependent on result MySQL create operation is getting executed before MySQL create operation sends results back.

Here is my code

1. calculation.js

   ```
   var mysql = require("mysql");
   var methods = {};

   // Creating connection
   methods.executeQuery = function(selectQuery, values){

   var result;

   var con = mysql.createConnection({
       host: "localhost",
       user: "root",
       password: "*********",
       database: "******"
   });

   // getting connection
   con.connect(function(err){
       if(err){
           console.log('Error connecting to Db');
           return;
       }
       console.log('Connection established');
   });

   con.query(selectQuery, values, function(err,rows){
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log(rows);
       result = rows;
       console.log(result);
       return result;
   });

   }

   module.exports = methods;
   ```
2. client.js

   ```
   var execute = require("./calculate.js");

   var selectQuery = 'INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES (?,?)';
   var values = ['sohamsoham12','sohamsoham12'];

   var insertedRowInfo = execute.executeQuery(selectQuery, values);

   if(insertedRowInfo){
       console.log("true");
   }else{
       console.log("false");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I correctly understand your question (what is the "create operation", for example?). But...
You can try this solution: execute the query inside the connect success callback:

```
// getting connection and executing query
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');

    con.query(selectQuery, values, function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(rows);
        result = rows;
        console.log(result);
        return result; // this can't work... you should invoke a callback function, here...
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**:
After OP comment, I now fully understand the question... (sorry :-().
You just miss a bit of async behavior... :-)

You should simply change `methods.executeQuery` from

```
function(selectQuery, values) {
  ...
}
```

to

```
function(selectQuery, values, callback) {
  ...
}
```

Then, instead using

```
return result;
```

You should simply use

```
callback(err, result); // if any error occurred
```

or

```
callback(null, result); // if no error occurred
```

Then, in `client.js`, when calling the `executeQuery` method, instead of

```
var insertedRowInfo = execute.executeQuery(selectQuery, values);
```

You should simply do

```
execute.executeQuery(selectQuery, values, function(err, insertedRowInfo) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle success, using insertedRowInfo...
  }
});
```

Comment: The question is very simple, All my code is working fine but in `client.js` when I call `var insertedRowInfo = execute.executeQuery(selectQuery, values);` I want the code after above statement wait till result come back and once result comes, if it success i want to console true else false. But right  now it not waiting result that why its going in else block all time